# iOS cordova app not loading content from external url

Tags: ios, cordova, browser, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have a problem with an App in Apache Cordova 4.0.0. The app start and load an external website in a _self browser with the command window.open().

Everything works fine except for one page: http://si3.bcentral.cl/bdemovil/BDE/ViewTwitter?menuId=NO&parentMenuName=Novedades

This page load perfectly in safari in the device, but in my app doesn't load the content of the twitter feed iframe.

Any ideas why this happen?

This problem only occurs in iOS, Android, Windows Phone no problems at all.

Comment: Is this happening just in the simulator or device too?

Comment: In the emulator and the device. I think there is an ajax call when the page load, that maybe is not happening in the app browser, but in safari does.
I have tried with the plugin inappbrowser, but doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was my mistake, I wasn't using properly the InappBrowser. I changed the _self target to _blank and the content load perfectly to my app. Then in the options you can hide the toolbar and button.